# Finding Uniswap v3 Token Reserves

Tags: uniswap

In Uniswap V2, we can use SYNC event to monitor the reserve changes in a pool for `token0` and `token1`. How can we do the same with Uniswap V3? If it can't be done through any event, what function can I call to check the reserve based on certain pool?

Answer (score 3):

You can directly use the erc20 balanceOf function to get the reserves from a particular pool. For example,

```
address pairAddress = "PAIR ADDRESS OF TOKEN0 AND TOKEN1";

uint256 reserve0 = IERC20(token0).balanceOf(pairAddress);
uint256 reserve1 = IERC20(token1).balanceOf(pairAddress);
```

Answer (score -1):

All available functions of uniswap v3 pool is here:
https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v3-core/blob/main/contracts/UniswapV3Pool.sol

```
function balance0() private view returns (uint256);
function balance1() private view returns (uint256);
```

every pool has these functions which return pool reserves.

Comment: Do you know which function I should use? 

Comment: function balance0() private view returns (uint256);
function balance1() private view returns (uint256);

Comment: Both of those functions are private meaning they cannot be called from outside of the smart contract they are defined within. Also, they use the ERC20 balanceOf method to obtain the balances which you can do yourself.